# How to safely create an ActiveRecord class method that unambiguously specifies a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to create a utility method on `ApplicationRecord`, like this:

```
def self.created_since(time)
  where('created_at > ?', time)
end
```

But when this is composed into a chain of methods involving other tables, the column reference becomes ambiguous and I get an error:

```
Foo.includes(:bars).created_since(3.days.ago)
--> SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."foo_id" = "foos"."id" WHERE (created_at > '2018-01-31 22:47:30.758235')
```

I would like to fix this problem. What is the best way to do so?

One way:

```
def self.created_since(time)
  where("#{table_name}.created_at > ?", time)
end
```

But this is interpolating directly into a SQL string, which opens me up to an injection attack in the unlikely scenario that the attacker controls `table_name`.

(e.g. I'm IKEA and the `Table < ApplicationRecord` model defines `table_name` by concatenating some user-supplied data)

Another attempt:

```
def self.created_since(time)
  where("?.created_at > ?", table_name, time)
end
```

does not work, as we get quotes around the table name

```
--> SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."foo_id" = "foos"."id" WHERE ('users'.created_at > '2018-01-31 22:47:30.758235')
```

and that's a syntax error.

Comment: In your example, is `created_since` supposed to be a filter on `Foo` or `Bar`?

Comment: if you're trying to do a utility method, my guess is that you're doing it as a module, right? you can get the table name from the class `self.class.table_name` and then pass it to the scope. No need to worry about injection attacks... might not work with complex queries, but you'll need to verify that (trial - error)

Comment: @jvillian It is supposed to be a filter on `Foo`.

Comment: @mr_sudaca Why wouldn't I need to worry about injection attacks if I use `self.class.table_name`?

Comment: don't know how would be possible to change that value, from what I understand, the only way to set a different value for that attribute it's by doing it explicitly in the model

Answer (score 0):

You could set a global scope and Table name can be passed as argument to 
scope.

```
# app/models/concerns/created_since.rb

module CreatedSince
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :created_since, -> (time, table = self.table_name){ where("#{table}.created_at >= ?", time) }
  end
end

# app/models/application_record.rb

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  include CreatedSince
end

# Usage
Foo.includes(:bars).created_since(3.days.ago)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you explain how this addresses the injection issue?

Comment: I don't think it is vulnerable or raise injection issues since you will have to explicitly change `table_name` value to alter the query.